# Debugging a "Failed to acquire connection" error in Play 2.0 app on Heroku

Tags: mysql, heroku, playframework-2.0

I'm switching to Heroku and trying to commit a Play 2.0 Project using ClearDB. All seems to compile fine, except I get an error when Heroku tries to start the application:

```
2012-08-02T18:10:45+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2012-08-02T18:10:45+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-08-02T18:10:48+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-08-02T18:10:48+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `target/start -Dhttp.port=47334 -Ddb.default.url=mysql://bf64fa6afab971:4b5fe3e5@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_32ef64c5764c759?reconnect=true -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops`
2012-08-02T18:10:51+00:00 app[web.1]: Play server process ID is 2
2012-08-02T18:10:51+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2012-08-02T18:10:52+00:00 app[web.1]: [error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 10. Exception: null
```

I've done all the Googling and research but have no idea what's causing the error:

**Procfile**

```
web: target/start -Dhttp.port=$PORT -Ddb.default.url=$CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL -DapplyEvolutions.default=true $JAVA_OPTS
```

**application.conf**

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

**heroku conf**

```
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL: mysql://myusername:mypassword@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_32ef64c5764c759?reconnect=true
DATABASE_URL:         postgres://myusername:mypassword@ec2-107-20-235-95.compute-1.amazonaws.com/sbzwmvjnqs
ENVIRONMENT_MODE:     stage
JAVA_OPTS:            -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops
PATH:                 .sbt_home/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
REPO:                 /app/.sbt_home/.ivy2/cache
SBT_OPTS:             -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops
SHARED_DATABASE_URL:  postgres://myusername:mypassword@ec2-107-20-235-95.compute-1.amazonaws.com/sbzwmvjnqs
```

Comment: Hopefully you rotated them out a long time ago, but you have database credentials in your edit history in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was the last configuration issue before I got Play Framework 2.0.2 to work with MySQL (through ClearDB) on Heroku.

Although it wasn't giving an actual error, it was just saying:

```
2012-08-02T18:10:52+00:00 app[web.1]: [error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 10. Exception: null
```

The actual problem turned out to be that Heroku on "standard free" mode, with ClearDB just gives you 10 simultaneous connections. I've seen it mentioned before that by default, play will use 60 connections.

**Solution:**

In application.conf, add:

```
db.default.partitionCount=1
db.default.maxConnectionsPerPartition=5
db.default.minConnectionsPerPartition=1
db.default.acquireIncrement=1
db.default.acquireRetryAttempts=1
db.default.acquireRetryDelay=5 seconds
```